# automorhpism of a vector space leaving direct sum invariant

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

I was reading Sadri Hassani book in which the author proves that if an automorphism of a vector space leaves one summand of a direct sum invariant, then the other one is invariant as well. The proof is as follows:-

[image: proof]

I cannot understand why you have $T(V_1\oplus V_2) = T(V_1)\oplus T(V_2)$. The statement also seems wrong to me as if you suppose a 2 dimensional space with the automorphism operator $T$ given by(in matrix notation):-

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 
  \end{bmatrix}
The vector $V_1$ could be your x axis and $V_2$ be the y axis. Now, T leaves the x axis invariant but doesn't leave the y axis invariant. Where is my understanding wrong?

Comment: The proof of the fact is surely wrong, V_1 + V_2 = V_1 + V_2' does not imply V_2=V_2'.
And yes, your example is a counter-example to the result in general $T: (x,y) \rightarrow (x,x+y)$ is an automorphism that fixes the space $\{(x,0)\}$ but does not fix $\{(0,y)\}$ even though $\{(x,0)\}\oplus \{(0,y)\} = \mathbb{F}^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a side note to my comment, the step you had issues with is correct, in fact:
$T(V_1 \oplus V_2) = T(V) = V$
For every $v \in V$ we have that $v = T(w)$ and therefore $v = T(v_1+v_2) = T(v_1)+T(v_2)$ so $T(V_1) + T(V_2) = V$.
To see that the sum is direct, if $v \in T(V_1) \cap T(V_2)$ then $v = T(v_1) = T(v_2)$ but then $T(v_1-v_2) = 0$ which would imply $v_1 = v_2$ and therefore $v_1=v_2=0 \Rightarrow v=0$.

The problem lies in the assumption that $V_1 \oplus V_2 = V_1 \oplus V_2' \Rightarrow V_2 = V_2'$, as a counterexample you can take the spaces you just mentioned, $V_1 = \{(x,0)|x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, $V_2 = \{(0,y)| y \in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $V_2'=\{(x,x)|x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.